# Add PNG image to PHP image

Tags: php, html, image, dynamic

I have problem with add a image to dynamic image in PHP:
This is my code:

```
<?php
$my_img = imagecreate( 500, 70 );
$background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 255 );
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );
$line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );

imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, getStatus(), $text_colour );
imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img);

imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $background );
imagedestroy( $my_img );


function getStatus(){
    include_once 'status.php'; //include the class
    $status = new MinecraftServerStatus(); // call the class
    $response = $status->getStatus('XXX'); // call the function 
    if(!$response) {
        return "Offline :(";
    } else {
        return ("Online: " . $response['players']);
    }
}

?>
```

The result is: http://kukubaczek.cf/s/sign.php And I want to add a background image: http://kukubaczek.cf/s/tlo.png How to do that?

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future visitors to SO.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php Should help you out

Comment: Awesome glad I could help you out.

Comment: Since @Jordy comment solved the problem you can answer you own question showing what you did